# Multivalue properties in an object relational mapping (Android application)

Tags: java, android, orm, relational-database

In an Android application I am building I am encapsulating the relational queries in a model layer.

One of my objects, let's call it `Place`, has a multivalue property (let's call it `Image`). Simplifying things I could say that the model in Java looks like:

```
class Place{
    List<Image> images;
    ...
}


class Image {
    String description;
    String imageName;
    ...
}
```

In the database these classes are mapped to the tables PLACE and IMAGE.

In the Java side I am using a DAO to query, insert, update, and delete `Place` objects.

As a simplified example, I would like to have a class called `PlaceDataSource` that looks like:

```
class PlaceDataSource {
    public List<Place> findAll();
    public void update(Place place);
    public void add(Place place);
    public void delete(Place place);
    ...
}
```

The description of these methods are the following:

The `findAll` method answers a list of `Place`s, each of them containing a collection of `Image` objects.

The `update` method updates a `Place` and its images (updating, inserting new images, or deleting existing images if necessary).

The `add` method adds a new `Place` with its images.

The `delete` method deletes a `Place` with all its images.

The `findAll`, `add` and `delete` methods are very easy to implement.
However, I have not seen a straightforward way of implementing the `update` method, that takes into consideration the multivalue property. The procedural algorithm that comes to my mind is:

- Querying from the database the currently persisted images from the `Place` object to update.
- Find out which `Image` objects are not present anymore in the `images` property of the `Place` object and delete them.
- Update the persisted images that exists in the `images` property.
- Add new images present in the `images` property.

I think this code is going to be ugly and inefficient. 
Is there a better way to implement the DAO ?
In your applications using DAOs, do you prefer to have each DAO mapped always to exactly one physical table ?

I have thought about using two different DAOs in this scenario, one for persisting `Place` objects and another for `Image` objects. Then the `Place` DAO would not be responsible for the persistance of image objects, but rather the 'business' layer should keep them consistent.
However, `Image`s are conceptually part of `Place` objects, so this solution does not completely convince me neither.

Thanks a lot for your feedback !

Note: at the moment I am not interested  in using an ORM framework for Android, just would like to find an answer to this problem from a conceptual point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) which does all of this for you but there are a couple of ways you can do this yourself.

You could write your own `List` class (`Collection` would be easier) that implements the methods that you want: `add`, `remove`, etc..  These would both change the list and call through the DAO methods.  For an example code, you could take a look at how ORMLite does this [`BaseForeignCollection`](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormlite-core/trunk/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseForeignCollection.java?revision=2244&view=markup) and [`EagerForeignCollection`](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormlite-core/trunk/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/EagerForeignCollection.java?revision=2281&view=markup) but it's probably overkill for your needs.

Easier would be as you mention to maintain the list by hand.  Maybe add methods on the `PlaceDataSource` (that seems like a DAO more than a `DataSource`) that would remove both from the list *and* the database.  Something like:

```
class PlaceDataSource {
    /** deletes image at location index from list and removes from database */
    public void deleteImage(Place place, int index);
    /** add image to the list and to the database */
    public void addImage(Place place, Image image);
    ...
```

You'll have to make sure that you do not use the list directly otherwise it will get out of sync with the database.

You could also have these methods on the `Place` itself and then have each `Place` object be injected with its DAO.  Some people like this pattern but I've always thought that having the DAO methods in another class was cleaner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the pointer to ORMLite @Gray. Do you think that the solution of having two DAOs (one for the Places and one for the Images) that would be used in the same Android activity is also a valid one ? (anyway it does not seem to exist a 'perfect' solution to this) or would you not recommend me at all to do that ? (if so why ?). Out of curiosity: does ORMLite work with byte code instrumentation at runtime or does it generate code at compilation time?

Comment: If you deal with Images and Places differently then 2 DAOs may be better.  If you only deal with Place objects then 1 is fine.  ORMLite would save you a lot of code but it is heavy.  It works with runtime annotations or configurations -- it does not do code generation.  Best of luck.